# "At most one record can be returned by this subquery."

Tags: sql, ms-access

Whenever I try to execute this code I get a "At most one record can be returned by this subquery."

```
SELECT W.FullName AS [Full Name], W.Phone, W.Address, W.Age, J.Salary, J.Job
FROM Jobs J INNER JOIN Workers W ON J.JobID = W.JobID
WHERE J.Salary >15000 AND (SELECT Building FROM Departments WHERE Building Like 'A#')
ORDER BY J.Salary
```

However, this seems to work, but I don't understand why.

```
SELECT W.FullName AS [Full Name], W.Phone, W.Address, W.Age, J.Salary, J.Job
FROM Departments, Jobs AS J INNER JOIN Workers AS W ON J.JobID = W.JobID
WHERE J.Salary > 15000 AND Departments.Building Like 'A#'
GROUP BY W.FullName, W.Phone, W.Address, W.Age, J.Salary, J.Job
ORDER BY J.Salary
```

What's wrong with the subquery?

Comment: Because the subquery returned more than one record.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Thanks, I understand.

Comment: @RobertHarvey is the solution only the second query? I mean that I can't use a subquery here.

Comment: The solution is to craft your subquery in such a way that it only returns one record.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'll try this. Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **IN**:

```sql
WHERE 
    J.Salary > 15000 AND 
    Departments.Building IN (SELECT Building FROM Departments WHERE Building Like 'A#')
```

Comment: It requests to enter a parameter.

Comment: Then a field name or a table name is missing or misspelled.

Comment: This will certain help me find issues in the future. If I add Departments to FROM it will work, but I need to use 'GROUP BY'. I think I'll use the second option. Thanks anyway.